# How do I create table in SQL Server using group by query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using a query to create a new table in SQL Server using a select query.

My query is

```
create table test as
    select id, sum(marks) as marks 
    from student
    group by id
```

I'm getting error message in SQL Server. In Stackoverflow I found that instead of create table, SQL Server uses insert into. But I'm not getting how to write group by query using insert into. Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id,sum(marks) as marks 
INTO TEST
from student
group by id
```

Using `INTO` [clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you are allowed to materialized the result in a table (it can be temporary table as well). There are few limitations - columns must have name (alias) and duplicate names are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select (columns Name or Functions (Max , Min , Sum ...) 1 , 2 , ...) 
INTO (Destination table)
From (Source table)
GROUP BY (cloumns Name 1 , 2 , ...)
```